# How do I customize the display of radio buttons in a Django template?

Tags: html, django, radio-button

In my `forms.py`, I have this, where `supbplansTuple` is a tuple of tuples:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    subChoices= forms.ChoiceField(label=_("Choose plan"), widget=forms.RadioSelect, choices=subPlansTuple)
```

`subplansTuple` looks something like this:

```
(("plan_1234","$5 a month"),("plan_2345","$10 a month"))
```

`register.html` has this:

```
<form id="register-form" name="regForm" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in registration_form %}
        <p>{{ field }}</p>  
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Problem is, Django displays the radio buttons widget like this:

```
<p></p>
<ul id="id_subChoices">
  <li>
    <label for="id_subChoices_0"><input id="id_subChoices_0" name="subChoices" type="radio" value="plan_1234" required=""> $5 a month</label>
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="id_subChoices_1"><input id="id_subChoices_1" name="subChoices" type="radio" value="plan_2345" required=""> $10 a month</label>
  </li>
</ul>
<p></p>
```

I do not want the radio buttons to display this way. How do I customize the HTML, maybe to look something like [Boostrap's inline radio buttons](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_form_radio_inline).

Answer (score 2):

Your field object has attributes that allows you to render the inputs in isolation, so in the template you can use the `{{field.tag}}` that will render only the field tag and on top you can put a label and inside the label attribute for put the input id `{{field.id_for_label}}`. this way:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in registration_form %}
        <label for="{{field.id_for_label}}">{{field.choice_label}}</label>
        {{field.tag}}
    {% endfor %}
</form>
```

Then we can customize with `css` through the classes, using the browser to see their classes in the source code, or defining classes inside the forms class through the attrs property of the `RadioButton` class and using it in a `css` library, it's all at your discretion. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#radioselect

Answer (score 1):

In Django <1.11 you should write a custom widget render, you can find other solutions in different posts on StackOverflow.

> I do not want the radio buttons to display this way. How do I customize the HTML, maybe to look something like Boostrap's inline radio buttons.

Well, the code is quite simple at the end, you'll have to write a little class:

```
class SwitchRenderer(RadioFieldRenderer):
    outer_html = u'{content}'
    inner_html = u'{choice_value}{sub_widgets}'
```

And then use this class as renderer on your widget.

The sample below is another use case that can help.

Django version 1.9.x and I need to implement a radio button like this: https://codepen.io/JiveDig/pen/jbdJXR/

```css
.switch-field {
 display: flex;
 margin-bottom: 36px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field input {
 position: absolute !important;
 clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
 height: 1px;
 width: 1px;
 border: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.switch-field label {
 background-color: #e4e4e4;
 color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
 font-size: 14px;
 line-height: 1;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 8px 16px;
 margin-right: -1px;
 border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
 transition: all 0.1s ease-in-out;
}

.switch-field label:hover {
 cursor: pointer;
}

.switch-field input:checked + label {
 background-color: #a5dc86;
 box-shadow: none;
}

.switch-field label:first-of-type {
 border-radius: 4px 0 0 4px;
}

.switch-field label:last-of-type {
 border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
}

/* This is just for CodePen. */

.form {
 max-width: 600px;
 font-family: "Lucida Grande", Tahoma, Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-weight: normal;
 line-height: 1.625;
 margin: 8px auto;
 padding: 16px;
}

h2 {
 font-size: 18px;
 margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

```html
<form class="form">
 <h2>Is this awesome?</h2>
 <div class="switch-field">
  <input type="radio" id="radio-one" name="switch-one" value="yes" checked/>
  <label for="radio-one">Yes</label>
  <input type="radio" id="radio-two" name="switch-one" value="no" />
  <label for="radio-two">No</label>
 </div>
</form>
```

In order to do this I extended some classes:

```
class SwitchChoiceInput(RadioChoiceInput):
    def render(self, name=None, value=None, attrs=None, choices=()):
        if self.id_for_label:
            label_for = format_html(' for="{}"', self.id_for_label)
        else:
            label_for = ''
        attrs = dict(self.attrs, **attrs) if attrs else self.attrs
        return format_html(
            u'{} <label{}>{}</label>', self.tag(attrs), label_for, self.choice_label
        )


class SwitchRenderer(RadioFieldRenderer):
    choice_input_class = SwitchChoiceInput
    outer_html = u'{content}'
    inner_html = u'{choice_value}{sub_widgets}'
```

Finally in the form, I used the renderer created:

```
field_switch = NullBoleanField(widget=RadioSelect(
                                          choices=[(True, 'Yes') (False, 'No')],
                                          renderer=SwitchRenderer))
```

I hope the solution helps somebody that like me, arrived on this post.

Answer (score 0):

In Django 1.11+, form widget rendering is done using the template system, so you could override "django/forms/widgets/radio.html", for example.

However, I would recommend using [django-crispy-forms](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms). It really helps with controlling the way forms get rendered.